# "Operation not permitted" when I tried to change ownership and permissions

Tags: linux-mint

How can I fix the "Operation not permitted" problems below?

```
~$ sudo nano /usr/local/bin/Fancontrol_Hddtemp
~$ chown root:root /usr/local/bin/Fancontrol_Hddtemp
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/local/bin/Fancontrol_Hddtemp': Operation not permitted
~$ chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/Fancontrol_Hddtemp
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/bin/Fancontrol_Hddtemp': Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be root to change ownership. Use commands on this way:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/Fancontrol_Hddtemp
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/Fancontrol_Hddtemp
```

Comment: I have asked a stupid question. I should have thought up the answer.

Comment: @MatthewWai, there are no stupid questions, there can be stupid answers :)

Comment: @ Romeo Ninov, how can I undo the two commands? I want to move the script to another location.

Comment: @MatthewWai, you do not need to undo. Just move the script

Comment: Do I need to change the permissions and ownership again after moving/renaming the script? Will the effect of the original commands automatically disappear after the script has been moved/renamed?

Comment: @MatthewWai, no, you do not need to change anything. The only thing which will change is the location of the file/script

Comment: Do you mean the permissions and ownership were actually stored in the script file, so I do not need to change anything? I have already deleted the original buggy script and will create a new one, possibly with a new name.

Comment: @MatthewWai, no, those attributes are not stored in script, they are part of file definition and when you exec `mv` command the OS will take care to keep them. If you create new file you will need to exec the above command again

Comment: I just found [this page](http://www.linfo.org/file.html). If I have understood correctly, such attributes (information) as permissions and ownership are attached to a file rather than saved to the OS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90314/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-matthew-wai).